# How to solve .NET7 csproj issues with compli

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-studio-2022

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise Version 17.3.3. When I start VS and open/create a **.NET 7** project, it gives me the following errors after opening any `.cs` file:
[image]
here is the log:

> =====================
> 2022-12-21 10:27:35
> Recoverable
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecutionException: Index was outside the bounds of the array. ---> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NodeStateTable`1.Single() at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TransformNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder builder, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TransformNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder builder, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BatchNode`1.UpdateStateTable(Builder builder, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TransformNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder builder, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TransformNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder builder, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CombineNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.TransformNode`2.UpdateStateTable(Builder builder, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SourceOutputNode`1.UpdateStateTable(Builder graphState, NodeStateTable`1 previousTable, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.DriverStateTable.Builder.GetLatestStateTableForNode[T](IIncrementalGeneratorNode`1 source) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SourceOutputNode`1.AppendOutputs(IncrementalExecutionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.GeneratorDriver.UpdateOutputs(ImmutableArray`1 outputNodes, IncrementalGeneratorOutputKind outputKind, Builder generatorRunStateBuilder, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Builder driverStateBuilder) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.GeneratorDriver.RunGeneratorsCore(Compilation compilation, DiagnosticBag diagnosticsBag, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.GeneratorDriver.RunGenerators(Compilation compilation, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionState.CompilationTracker.<FinalizeCompilationAsync>d__39.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionState.CompilationTracker.<BuildFinalStateFromInProgressStateAsync>d__36.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionState.CompilationTracker.<BuildCompilationInfoAsync>d__32.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionState.CompilationTracker.<GetOrBuildCompilationInfoAsync>d__31.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.SolutionState.CompilationTracker.<GetCompilationSlowAsync>d__29.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Properties.StartupObjectsEnumGenerator.<GetListedValuesAsync>d__8.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.PropertyPages.PageDynamicEnumProperty.<CreateAdmissibleValuesAsync>d__6.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.SupportedValueDataProducer.<CreateSupportedValuesAsync>d__1.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.VS.Query.QueryDataFromProviderStateProducerBase`1.d__0.MoveNext()
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<RunQueryOnceAsync>d__9.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ProjectSystem.Query.QueryExecution.QuerySubscription`1.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()

When I try to go to project properties, this log is shown instead of the default items. IntelliSense doesn't work and VS treats my `.cs` files like normal text files. There is only the coloring feature for my codes. The projects however compile successfully. If I add `<EnableDefaultCompileItems>false</EnableDefaultCompileItems>` to the csproj file and then import the files manually, everything is back to normal. But it's not possible because I have a solution that is recently upgraded to .NET 7 and doesn't work either. There are many projects and items in this solution so I can not (and rather not to) import every file manually.
My csproj file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: .net7 requires VS2022 to be updated to version 17.4, that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written in this blog, [.NET 7 is part of Visual Studio 2022 17.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-4/#net-7).

So if you need .Net 7, please update to the latest version.

Like [17.4](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/)

If you're after something stable, you can use .Net 6.

Comment: .NET 7 is officially released in November 8th and should be stable for enterprise purposes. I updated Visual Studio and now it's working as expected. Thank you.